# Finding all docs with specific reference in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On Cloud Firestore I have documents with reference to another document this way:

[image: Reference from collection A to B]

In my example, document `Collection A/WJQ9yx67RrqHWQoEp0e2` is referring to document `Collection B/rFOEwdw5go4dbitOCXyC`, but there of course, could be infinitely docs referring to one mentioned.

Now I would like to find out all the docs of `Collection A` which are referring to this very specific document `Collection B/rFOEwdw5go4dbitOCXyC`.

**How is this possible? How I can achieve this?**

Documentation of Firebase is bit unclear with this.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Personally I'm using JavaScript on Web. But I think this question generally covers all the languages supported by Firebase.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're right, there's unfortunately no example of actually making use of a `Reference` data type in the documentation, in fact the only a mention of it is in the [Supported Data Types section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

Ultimately though, a `Reference` can be used just like any other data type available in Firestore, so can be used to filter & sort data too.

To achieve what you're after, you would need to construct a `Reference` that points to the document in `Collection B` and then use a `where` clause to filter data on the `reference` value of `Collection A`. For example in JavaScript:

```
// Create a reference to the specific document you want to search with
var reference = db.collection("Collection B").doc("rFOEwdw5go4dbitOCXyC");

// Construct a query that filters documents matching the reference
var query = db.collection("Collection A").where("reference", "==", reference);
```

Looking at the [source for `isEqual()` in the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/73a586c92afe3f39a844b2be86086fddb6877bb7/packages/database/src/api/Query.ts#L607), comparing of a `Reference` (extends `Query`) is performed by simply checking that the paths match:

> ```
>   isEqual(other: Query): boolean {
>     // [...]
>     const sameRepo = this.repo === other.repo;
>     const samePath = this.path.equals(other.path);
>     const sameQueryIdentifier =
>       this.queryIdentifier() === other.queryIdentifier();
>
>     return sameRepo && samePath && sameQueryIdentifier;
>   }
> ```

This would seem to be much like calling `toString()` on both and comparing the string values.

I produced a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907058/2754146) yesterday which lead me to test the possible uses of storing a `Reference`, so that may also apply here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just got it working! After all, the solution was easier than I ever thought :)