# Get Firestore document as plain Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently manually itearting over document fields in firestore and putting them into an object which I stringify to JSON.

Is there a way to automate the process? Something like:

```
var userEnrollments = ToJson(await admin.firestore().collection(USERS + "/" + x.uid + "/" + ENROLMENT));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/DocumentSnapshot) has a method [data()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) that returns the entire contents (without subcollections) of the document as a plain JavaScript object.

```
admin.firestore().doc('path/to/doc').get().then(snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.data()  // a plain JS object 
})
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to capture references.

For example the enrolment document has a reference to a curriculum document but using snapshot.data() shows that as a documentreference rather than the plain JS object..

Comment: Right, that's how it works. All document reads in Firestore are shallow.  You have to query again to get the next doc.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for

Comment: That makes me very sad, I guess it would make more sense to store the IDs to those references to get deep copies working instead which kind of defeats the purpose of this whole thing..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900906/whats-the-difference-between-using-a-documentreference-in-firestore-and-using-j  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for/46570119

Comment: Alternatively: `const document = await firestore.collection("lol").doc("hi").get(); console.log(document.data());`

Answer (score 0):

Try use observable

```
var userEnrollments = Observable<User>;
Document userDoc = this.db.doc<User>('User/'+id);
this.userEnrollments = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
```

You can use array like: `Observable<User[]>;` with `FirestoreCollection<User>;`

I use similar in angular fire. 
You can use `ASYNC` in firebase too.